# redirection problem for test.example.com to example.com in apache

Tags: django, apache, apache2

I have a site `example.com` and another one `test.example.com`. Both have different configuration file. But when I enter url `test.example.com` it redirects to `example.com`.

```
configuration file for example.com

 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot example-document-path

  Options -Indexes

  ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
  ErrorDocument 403 /errors/404.html

 <Location "/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    PythonPath "['path', 'path'] + sys.path"
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE example.settings
    PythonInterpreter example
    PythonAutoReload On
    PythonDebug On
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Apache configuration file for test.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  test.example.com
  ServerAlias www.test.example.com

  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot test-example-document-path

  Options -Indexes

  ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
  ErrorDocument 403 /errors/404.html

 <Location "/foo/bar/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    PythonPath "['path', 'path'] + sys.path"
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE example.settings
    PythonInterpreter example
    PythonAutoReload On
    PythonDebug On
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

The root url test.example.com redirects to example.com which i don't want?
How i have no clue? Can anyone please suggest something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a real question: if this is not what you want, what do you want then?

Comment: @koneark, I wnat that test.example.com should not be directed to example.com.

Comment: You should really rename your question to reflect what you want to know as well.

Comment: Don't you think it would be more useful to post configuration for "test.example.com" as it's the site you are trying to access ?

Answer (score 2):

First guess would be cache issue, second guess would be your `index.html` (or `.php` or whatever) file on test.example.com.  If it's not either of those, run:

```
$ curl -vvv test.example.com
```

And see what headers its sending back. They will give you some clues about the nature of the redirect. If that doesn't solve it, post the output here.

**Edit**: Alright, if you're getting a 302 from Apache, there is only a limited number of things that could be responsible. The things that come to mind are:

- `.htaccess` file in the `test.example.com` root
- `Redirect` and `Alias`  directives in Apache config (`egrep -R 'Redirect|Alias' /etc/apache2/`)
- `ModRewrite` rules with redirects (`egrep -R '\bR\b' /etc/apache2/`)

Also, verify that you're *actually* talking to the server you expect to be talking to (eg, `curl http://test.example.com/blahblahblah`, then grep the access log for `blahblahblah`).

Comment: Hi, David! The response from the curl request clearly shows that there is 302 somewhere but where it's coming from we have no clue? Can you throw some more light on this? Thank you so much.

Comment: hey david, I have same query. So, I just posted the response here.

Comment: Hey guys, I've updated my answer with some more possibilities. Give them a try and see if they work.

Comment: Thanks David. There was an .htaccess file and rewite rule was written here.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this has to do with the DNS settings. I doubt it has anything to do with Apache. There is probably an alias record pointing test.example.com to example.com OR a wildcard alias record pointing *.example.com to example.com.

Comment: In the DNS test.example.com has been added as A record? Is it because of that?

Comment: And their is CNAME record for example.com is:  CNAME (Alias) Record Name: wwww .example.com.

Comment: I doubt it's a DNS issue… There's nothing could do that would cause a 302 redirect. If anything, DNS could be pointing to a bad server (eg, `test.example.com` points to `old_server.example.com`), and the Apache on the bad server is misconfigured…

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't realize it was getting a 302 redirect. But you're right, none of those DNS settings you mentioned would cause it to redirect to the other domain.

Comment: Make sure that the index.html file doesn't do the 302 redirect with a meta tag also


<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/" />